# Passing variable to a class in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, oop, parameter-passing

It is my first time asking a question here and I am quite new to MATLAB. So, I am sorry in advance if my explanation is faulty or insufficient. I'll be happy to hear any advice to improve myself.

I would like to create a class which has an array of a certain size. Let's call this class 'MyClass'. My class is as follows:

```
    classdef MyClass
       properties 
           A = array2table(zeros(ArraySize,1));
       end
    end
```

The variable ArraySize is defined in my main.m file and i want to create an object from this class within the same file:

```
    ArraySize = 10;
    MyObject = MyClass;
```

However, the class I created does not recognize the ArraySize variable. Could somebody tell me if there is an easy way to achieve this?
So far, I tried to make it a global variable, I tried using 'load' function to pass parameters between files. I tried defining the class inside a function. None of them seem to work. I read about 'handles' in forums and i got the idea that it somehow can be related to the solution of my problem, but I do not really know how to work with them. What I understood so far is that handles correspond to pointers in C++. I would like to know if they can be used to solve my problem and if so, how exactly.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't think of handles as corresponding to pointers from C++. They are really not the same. Just think of value vs. handle classes as being a difference in the copy semantics of the classes.

Answer (score 2):

You should just write your constructor to accept `ArraySize` as an input argument and then initialize the value `A` inside of your constructor.

```
classdef MyClass
   properties 
       A
   end

   methods 
       function self = MyClass(arraySize)
           self.A = array2table(zeros(arraySize,1));
       end
   end
end
```

And then instantiate your class

```
myObject = MyClass(ArraySize);
```

And with regards to `handle` classes, check out [this page of the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/which-kind-of-class-to-use.html) to see recommendations on when to use `handle` and value classes.

Comment: Thank you, but when I do as you say I get this error:                            
                                                                                                            
     Not enough input arguments.
     Error in MyClass (line 8)
     self.A = array2table(zeros(arraySize,1));

Comment: @elifcansu Yea because you have to actually pass the input to the constructor. See the update.